# Forcing IP fragmentation and reassembly for some traffic thru a VPN tunnel

Tags: linux, vpn, mtu, ip-fragmentation

Is there a way to force IP packet fragmentation before they go into tun0 and then force reassemble them on the other side of tun device?

I have some IPSec traffic that I can not control, and it wants 1500 MTU and just gets dropped at the tun device.

I guess it might be possible to encapsulate the traffic into TCP stream, then reassemble the stream back to packets - but it is definitely not how it should work due to various reasons. So I am wondering if there is a way to force fragmentation and reassembly for at least some matched packets at OS level in linux?

Comment: When packet reaches interface with lower MTU, it should be fragmented by default unless packet has 'no fragment' flag.

Comment: to clarify the problem: IPSec packets all come with DF set; MTU for tun0 is 1350; MTU for originating interface eth0 is 1500

Comment: then it is impossible, afaik

Comment: You may want to take a look at this, http://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter/2004-July/054802.html

Comment: `tun0` is a virtual network interface. Is there any reason you aren't simply changing the MTU?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
 ip link set mtu xxx dev tun0
```

where xxx is whatever you deem appropriate?

**EDIT**:

you may want to take a look at [this](http://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter/2004-July/054802.html): this guy has a problem similar to yours,

> I have same problem some time later. My uplink not pass tcp-packets whith=
>   =20
>   length more then 1496 bytes. I solve this by cleaning DF-bit in all outgo=
>   ing =20
>   tcp-packets. Linux by default not allow clear Df-bit and I'm wrote small=20
>   kernel modules and patch for iptables for clearning DF-bit.
>
> Use:
>   for clear DF on outgoing packets:

```
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j DF --clear
```

> for clean DF on incoming packets:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j DF --clear
```

> And also other iptables options is allowning.

The refs to his code are dead, but you can try writing him,  avl@strace.net.

Comment: all packets come with DF set. MTU is actually 1350 on tun0, but all the packets get dropped due to DF

Comment: thank you for the links! Regarding the DF clear: as far as I understand, linux will not reassemble packets and they have to travel all the way to receiver through the wild net, and then hopefully be reassembled by actual receiver which I do not control too. AFAIK, fragmented packets are likely to be dropped in the wild, so the second part to force immediate reassembly is still open. Actually I am wondering why is this task so non-popular that I cannot google out the solution.

Comment: What is the option for this in iptables6? I need to fragment a IPv6 packet in order to see if our product handles IP fragments correctly

Comment: I get `iptables v1.6.1: unknown option "--clear"`. Why doesn't it work for me?

Comment: @Aenfa that is not part of default iptables; would require patching (and the link to the patch is dead)